# Do I need to install OpenCV if needed files were given?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, visual-studio-2013, 32bit-64bit

I'm trying to run a multi-project Solution in Visual Studios 2013 and in these files the original developer included the OpenCv files used in the program.  I was wondering if I still need to download and install OpenCv, if he already included them?

And if I do, do I have to get the same version of OpenCV?

Also, it seems that the original developer was using a x86 computer.  Is it possible that his code might not work on my x64 computer since there are some files that specifically say theyre for Win32?

Thanks

Comment: you dont need to install anything if header, libs and dlls are given. your compiler must fit the libs though, so if you have 32 bit libs for visual studio 2010 you have to compile a 32 bit binary with vc100 compiler

Comment: Was he using same visual studio that you are going to use? If so, then you will be fine. For x64, yes you can run apps that was designed for x86 in a PC with x64 arch.. You better stick with 32bit unless you have to use 64bit. If you seriously want to work with OpenCV, then compile it by your compiler. I've tested OpenCV 3 with visual studio 2013 and it wasn't really hard.

Comment: @Micka, I downloaded 32 bit versions of everything the program needed and used the opencv files that were given in the folder. Thanks! Its finally been able to generate the code.